# Set notation meaning

Tags: notation

When you write $x\in R$, this reads $x$ is an element of $R$. This specifies a domain for $x$ which is simply a variable.

When you define a set $X = \{x\}$ , the set of all $x$, or $X = \{x\in R\}$ it seems as though to define the set you are specifying a domain for $x$, the values $x$ can take is the set. My question is how would you refer to $x$? I know you can refer to it as the general element but I can't really understand this.

Comment: To be precise, instead of $\{x\in R\}$ it is more consistent to write it as $\{x|x\in R\}$. Having said that, it seems you are asking about the issue of [variable vs constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859288/92427).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X = \{x\}$ says $X$ is a set and it has one element in it.

If you want to define a set $X$ and then say for all $x\in X$ that is fine.  You don't need anything else other than "for set $X$" or similar.  Heck, you often don't even need to say that much.

And if you need to be more specific, you may want to say that $X$ is a subset of the natural numbers. i.e. $X\subset \mathbb N$

And maybe you want to define a set like the set of point on the unit circle.  $X=\{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$

Comment: Thanks, if your last line defines the set of points on the unit circle then why does X = {x} not define the set of all x because your not placing any restriction on x?

Comment: Then how would you define the set which contained the element x?  I do see your point.  Nonetheless, if you want $X$ to be most generically a set, then just say so.  If you want to put conditions on the elements then define the conditions.

Comment: You *have* to impose conditions, because there is no "set of everything". That would actually result in logical errors if there was such a thing.

Comment: You might also see something line $\{a\}$ is a sequence converging to $a.$  And sequences use many of the concepts and vocabulary as sets do.

Comment: @red_trumpet you might say $f:X\to Y$ is a function.  $X,Y$ are sets, but we might never get around to their particulars.  But we must assume that do meet the ZF requirements of a set (i.e. not the set of all sets, or similar)